# Some issues with section and chapter headers and equation numbering in amsbook

Tags: header-footer, numbering, amsbook

Using the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{amsbook}

\usepackage[width=17cm, left=2.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\newpage}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\makeatletter
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname r@tocindent0\endcsname{50.5pt}
\makeatother
}
\newcommand\atotoc[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{#1\par}}

\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{{\setcounter{theorem}{0}
\setcounter{equation}{0}}\section{\hspace{-5mm}.
\hspace{0.5mm}#1}\vspace{0cm}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\def\stackunder#1#2{\mathrel{\mathop{#2}\limits_{#1}}}
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\newline Theorem}[section]

    \renewcommand\citeform[1]{{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\Ifstr{\thetitle}{\thesection}{}{}\hspace{3mm}}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{20pt}}}{}{}

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\def\partrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#2}{{\@ifnotempty{#1}{#1 }}\@ifnotempty{#3}{}} \arabic{chapter}. #3}
\let\chapterrunhead\partrunhead
\def\sectionrunhead#1#2#3{ %
   \@ifnotempty{#2}{{\@ifnotempty{#1}{#1 }}\@ifnotempty{#3}{}} \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section} #3}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{The first part}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\section{Section 1 in chapter 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}

\section{Section 2 in chapter 1}
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum
\section{Section 3 in chapter 1}
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum
\section{Section 4 in chapter 1}
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]


\chapter{The second chapter}

\section{Section 1 in chapter 2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\section{Section 2 in chapter 2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\section{Section 3 in chapter 2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\section{Section 4 in chapter 2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I get some issues as shown in the figures below (from the output). When starting Chapter 2, the first section is numbered 2.6 and should be 2.1 (in the title on page 5). The same problem on page 9, where the headerd should be numbered 2.4 instead of 2.8.

Another issue concerns the numbering of the equations, e.g., on page 7, the fisrt equation should be numbered (2.1.1) instead of (2.5.1).

How can I solve these? Any hep would be appreciated.

*LE: How can I increase the font of the section and chapter headers?
And I want also to remove the section headers only for the unnumbered chapters, which are introduced by using `\chapter*{...}`, but I do not know how to do this.*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try removing the line `\@removefromreset{section}{chapter}`, which is preventing the section counter from being reset to 0 when the chapter changes. Not sure how that got there to begin with.

Comment: Yes, it works well, thank you! I have taken some commands from a topic here. One more thing, if possible. How can I increase the size of the section and chapter headers since this one seems too small.

Comment: I suspect you have taken the preamble from some friend of yours. Well, they didn't really know what they were doing. That code is really awful.

Comment: @egreg The commands are from stackexchange. I tried to adjust them to fix several problems.

Comment: @Cris Well, neither `geometry` and `titlesec` are really compatible with `amsbook`. And all the `\newsection` part is really wrong.

Comment: `amsbook` has nearly all of what you want built in.  The extra commands you have added to "adjust" the numbering have made them inoperative.  I suggest that you read the documentation that describes how it works.  It's the "monograph" option in this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/amscls-doc